# Something wrong with wtforms FieldList && validation

Tags: python, wtforms

Something wrong with wtforms FieldList && validation...
It should say that field must have Int value, not This field is required
Why f.data has [None, 2, None] value, not ['def', 2, 'abc'] ?

```
from webob.multidict import MultiDict

from wtforms import Form
from wtforms import FieldList, IntegerField
from wtforms import validators

class SearchForm(Form):
    locality_id = FieldList(IntegerField(u'Locality', [validators.Required()]))


d = MultiDict([('locality_id-0', 'def'), ('locality_id-1', 2), ('locality_id-2', 'abc')])

f = SearchForm(d)

print f.validate()
print f.errors
print f.data
print f.locality_id.data
```

% python form_test.py

False

{'locality_id': [[u'This field is required.'], [u'This field is required.']]}

{'locality_id': [None, 2, None]}

[None, 2, None]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a `try... except` block in the `IntegerField` ancestry which will place all non ints into the `process_errors` property and that the class is specifically prevented from allowing you to have data populated with anything but valid data. I believe you can still get the values you seek in the `raw_data` property, however.

Comment: `
class IntegerField(TextField): 
... 
   def process_formdata(self, valuelist): 
        if valuelist: 
            try: 
                self.data = int(valuelist[0]) 
            except ValueError: 
                raise ValueError(self.gettext(u'Not a valid integer 
value')) 
`

I cant get why I'm not getting 'Not a valid integer value' exception 
from process_formdata() ? Why I get 'This field is required.' ?